# Arrays Program Debugging

Tags: python, arrays

I am having a problem with debugging my program, the instructor said you only need to turn on or off the lines by using "#" or the comment sign in order for the program works. It is all about simple array in python only. Please help thank you

```
numbers = [10,20,300,40.5,50]

#random indexing --> O(1) get items if we know the index !!!
print(numbers[4]);

numbers[1] = 'Adam';

print(numbers[1]);

for num in numbers:
    print(num);

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    print(numbers[i]);

print(numbers[:-2]);

#O(N) search running time
maximum = numbers[0];
for num in numbers:
    if num > maximum:
        maximum = num;

print(maximum);
```

Answer (score 1):

comment out `numbers[1] = 'Adam'` so that you can do numerical comparison in the looping part.

Btw you don't need ";" in python

Comment: `;` is still a legal things in python. I see `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace` so often.

Comment: you can use `;` in python to put multiple statements in the same line. Adding it in the end of statements does nothing, but is not a syntax error either

Comment: Wow great! Thank you so much for this

Comment: Glad it helped and welcome to stack overflow! Try upvoting an answer if you find that helpful or accept an answer to let more people see it at top.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has error when 'Adam' compared with maximum. You must add checking if num not str, or you must add # to line: numbers[1] = 'Adam' to solve this problem

Comment: Wow great! Thank you so much for this